# Get all SMS from a particular number in inbox - Esendex

Tags: php, rest

I am using the Esendex Rest API http://developers.esendex.com/APIs/REST-API/inbox and I am trying to get all the messages in the inbox from a particular phone number.

This is basically so if I do a send out of SMS's and someone replies I am able to retrieve the reply.

I can currently get all the messages in the inbox into an array and sort them, but this is too slow with over 4000 messages.

Does anyone know if I can filter by phone number, or at least date-received in my API requests? Even if I could get the last weeks worth of SMS's.

Comment: *"P.S. Could a mod please add an esendex tag - thanks!"* -> this is for what Meta is for. Just ask there: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: The answer to "please make a tag" is "please demonstrate a tag is needed by asking questions about the thing you think needs a tag."

Comment: Filtering by phone number - do you mean just one phone number?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use the [conversation API](http://developers.esendex.com/APIs/REST-API/conversation) if you want to filter by a phone number. The drawback is that you can get only the latest 15 messages, also that there is no reliable way to detect if a reply has been received from a phone number other than the inbox API. Apart from this I wasn't able to find anything that can help you. Their API is very restrictive and minimal.

Comment: Perhaps you could drop me a note at support@esendex.com and let me know what functionality you'd like to see in our API.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no way to do this via the REST API but I'll see if we can add it over the next couple of weeks (I work for Esendex). As you note the functionality already exists in the Conversations API albeit in a more minimal form.

In the meantime you could achieve this by checking all messages that arrive either by polling the Inbox or using [Push Notifications](http://developers.esendex.com/APIs/Push-Notifications).

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for your input. When I send an SMS it is an appointment reminder from my appointment system. It asks the client to reply "Y" if they wish to confirm the appointment, "N" otherwise. I can currently get the entire inbox and iterate through it but they like to keep every sms, so it takes too long. It would be nice to get the last reply given a phone number in one function - that way I could just check if it is a Y or an N